# Escape accumulated arguments in a shell script?

Tags: shell, escaping

With a view to a [bug in git](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/192453), at the moment [git-submodule.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-submodule.sh) reads (reordered):

```
[iterating over command line arguments]
        --reference)
            case "$2" in '') usage ;; esac
            reference="--reference=$2"
            shift
            ;;
        --reference=*)
            reference="$1"
            shift
            ;;
[...]
        if test -n "$reference"
        then
            git-clone $quiet "$reference" -n "$url" "$path" --separate-git-dir "$gitdir"
        else
            git-clone $quiet -n "$url" "$path" --separate-git-dir "$gitdir"
        fi ||
        die "$(eval_gettext "Clone of '\$url' into submodule path '\$path' failed")"
```

This uses only the *last* argument given by `--reference`.  I now want to enhance this so that all `--reference` options are passed on to `git-clone`.  This is trivial for trivial arguments (`reference="$reference --reference=$2"`), but my mind boggles when thinking about arguments containing white space, quote or shell meta characters.

What is the best practice to escape such accumulated arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice would be to use a bash array:

```
declare -a references
#...
  --reference)
    case ... esac
    references+=("--reference=$2")
    shift
    ;;
  --reference=*)
    references+=("$1")
    shift
    ;;
#...
# no need to test the array for emptiness
git-clone $quiet "${references[@]}" -n "$url" "$path" --separate-git-dir "$gitdir"
```

However, the referenced script uses /bin/sh instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking for a general solution aside from the peculiarities of the git case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice when writing portable `#!/bin/sh` which cannot use arrays, assuming you actually need to pass through arbitrary arguments is to wrap every argument with single-quote (`'`) characters, after replacing every single-quote in the argument with `'\''`.

Let's say you have a function called `quote_for_shell` which lets you take one argument and quote it perfectly. Here's the simplest, unoptimized version of what that function might look like:

```bash
quote_for_shell()
{
    printf "'"
    printf '%s' "$1" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g"
    printf "'\n"
}
```

Then you could do this:

```bash
references=''
# ...
        --reference)
            case "$2" in '') usage ;; esac
            references="$references --reference=$(quote_for_shell "$2")"
            shift
            ;;
        --reference=*)
            references="$references $(quote_for_shell "$1")"
            shift
            ;;
```

But the trick is that you can't just do `git-clone $references` (or `git-clone "$references")` - the results of unquoted variable/command substitutions are not fully evaluated by the shell, they only get globbing and field splitting passes done to them (and quoted expansions are not evaluated with those passes either).

So you have to wrap that command in an `eval`, but it **must be** the *quoted* expansion that gets `eval`'ed, so that the `eval` seens the pristine whitespace and globbing characters exactly as they were escaped:

```bash
eval "git-clone $quiet $references # !!!"
```

But wait! All those other variables in the same command, which might have arbitrary characters in them, like `$url` and `$path`, now also end up in the `eval`, so they now also need to be escaped:

```bash
url="$(quote_for_shell "$url")"
path="$(quote_for_shell "$path")"
gitdir="$(quote_for_shell "$gitdir")"
eval "git-clone $quiet $references $url $path --separate-git-dir $gitdir"
```